# org.eclipse.swt.text, automatically truncate the text?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I have a `org.eclipse.swt.text` widget. Sometimes the widget isn't big enough to display all the information in it, is there a way to change the way it displays the information without changing the actual content?

I.e, it should show "1234...4321", but when I do `getText()` it should return the actual value "123456654321".

Or is there a different SWT widget that can handle this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do with the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text` because SWT actually works with the native widget set and on most OS the native text widget can have a single state i.e value.

The workaround is either you create `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text` with `SWT.MULTI|SWT.WRAP` flags or wrap the original text widget in an utility class.

**`>>Output`**

[image]

**`>>Sample Wrapper Code`**

```
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class MyText
{
    private Text text;
    private String value;
    public MyText(Composite parent, int style) {
        text = new Text(parent, style);
    }

    public Text getControl() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setText(String value) {
        if(text != null && !text.isDisposed()){
            this.value = value;
            text.setText(shortenText(value, text.getParent()));
        }
    }

    private String shortenText(String textValue, Control control)
    {
        if (textValue == null) {
            return null;
        }
        GC gc = new GC(control);
        int maxWidth = control.getBounds().width - 25;
        int maxExtent = gc.textExtent(textValue).x;

        System.out.println(maxWidth + "\n" + maxExtent);
        if (maxExtent < maxWidth) {
            gc.dispose();
            return textValue;
        }
        int length = textValue.length();
        int charsToClip = Math.round(0.95f*length * (1 - ((float)maxWidth/maxExtent)));
        int pivot = length / 2;
        int start = pivot - (charsToClip/2);
        int end = pivot + (charsToClip/2) + 1;
        while (start >= 0 && end < length) {
            String s1 = textValue.substring(0, start);
            String s2 = textValue.substring(end, length);
            String s = s1 + "..." + s2;
            int l = gc.textExtent(s).x;
            if (l < maxWidth) {
                gc.dispose();
                return s;
            }
            start--;
            end++;
        }
        gc.dispose();
        return textValue;
    }
}
```

**Note** the implementation of `shortenText()` method.

**`>>Main`**

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class TextWidgetTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Text Widget Test");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setSize(300, 200);

        final MyText text = new MyText(shell, SWT.SINGLE|SWT.BORDER);
        text.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        text.setText("A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text");

        Button show = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        show.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        show.setText("Show Actual Text");


        final Text console = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER|SWT.MULTI|SWT.WRAP|SWT.V_SCROLL);
        console.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        show.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                console.setText(text.getText());
            }
        });

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great way to do it. I'll probably do it like this.

Comment: You really put a lot of effort into this one :). My +1.

Answer (score 1):

Would creating the control with the SWT.MULTI|SWT.WRAP flags set be a good option for you? This way, you get a multiline control that wraps text.

Here's how to do it:

```
Text myText = new Text(parent, SWT.MULTI|SWT.WRAP);
```

Comment: Yea, that would work, but it'll probably end up looking bad it the GUI with several lines. I think I'm gonna go with Favonius example.

Comment: @Fredrik - Certainly, go with whatever suits your needs best. Glad you found your answer :).